# How can I configure a Client Hyper-V (on Windows 8) to connect to the host and other VMs without a network connection?

Tags: windows-8, hyper-v

I'm trying to develop an interface to an application that doesn't run on Windows 8.  Hence, I've created a VM with Windows 7 running the integration service and another service running on the Windows 8 host.

I have three Virtual Network scenarios configured for Hyper-V: Wireless, Shared and Internal.  Where Wireless allows all VMs and the host to connect to a wireless network (External), Shared let's the VMs connect through the host via a VPN (Internal) and Internal creates a network within the host where the VMs don't have network access (Private).

When I'm in Wireless (External) mode and there's a wireless network to connect to, everything works fine as if I were testing using to physical PCs on a wireless network.  However, today I had a situation where I wasn't connected to a network but still wanted to do some testing and I could not get the VM to see the host and vice-versa.  This scenario was quite straight forward to create on VMware which I used before switching to Hyper-V...

Has anyone managed to make Client Hyper-V VMs and the host communicate without a network?  Can you guide me how to set it up?

Comment: Thanks. I'll review those answers.  However, in multiple of those  cases the answers didn't help me resolve the issue and that's why I didn't mark any one as an answer so it doesn't mislead another member.  Thanks for your alert.

Answer (score 0):

Wireless networking under Windows 8 Hyper V can not communicate with multiple VM the Wireless NIC is assign to only one Hyper V internet connection,

Meaning only one Hyper V can connect to the Internet preventing others from connecting unless you use multiple Nic's Wireless Network Cards or USB Wireless Network.

It is only after you restart or shut down your computer that Hyper-V problems start.

So if you can not connect any of your Hyper VMs then you problem could be due to a shutdown error that Hyper-v in counted Try restarting the whole computer then Hyper- VMs your problem should fix itself.

Answer (score 0):

Might want to try this. I am having similar problems as you and all signs point to this particular solution working, but for me it is not. Might help you, though.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/doxley/archive/2008/07/07/disconnecting-hyper-v.aspx

The solution that DID end up working for me was this:
http://www.elmajdal.net/Win2k8/Enabling_Wireless_Network_For_Hyper_V_Virtual_Machine.aspx